# Making a React PWA, Trying to exclude specific API calls from caching

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I used create-react-app to start a PWA app, and am trying to make the service-worker work for me. I have the service-worker working to cache all my main code's html, js, css and fonts so it can work offline. But for the last couple of weeks I have been looking for specific information on configuring the workbox.config.js or service-worker.js so I can prevent it from trying to respond to my api requests.

I made a dummy app using the npx create-react-app my-app --template cra-template-pwa in order to get the latest (hopefully) service-worker JS code and applied the implementation to my index.js :-

```js
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import "./index.css"
import App from "./App"

import * as serviceWorkerRegistration from './serviceWorkerRegistration';

import { Provider } from "react-redux"
import store from "./redux/store"

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
serviceWorkerRegistration.register();
```

...and I have attempted to understand the lines in service-worker.js itself, added a section which I hoped would exempt API calls from caching...

```js
registerRoute(
  // Return false to exempt requests from being fulfilled by index.html.
  ({ request, url }) => {
    // If this isn't a navigation, skip.
    if (request.mode !== 'navigate') {
      return false;
    }
    // If this is a URL that starts with /_, skip.
    if (url.pathname.startsWith('/_')) {
      return false;
    }
    // *** added to try to exempt API calls from cache ***
    if (url.pathname.startsWith('/api/')) {
      return false;
    }
    // If this looks like a URL for a resource, because it contains a file extension, skip.
    if (url.pathname.match(fileExtensionRegexp)) {
      return false;
    } // Return true to signal that we want to use the handler.

    return true;
  },
```

...but whenever I press my "Refresh Data" button to go to the API to get current data it is served from Disk Cache even though I am connected to the network. It does not download current data from the API when requested (a GET request to /api/getallsongdata), rather it uses previously cached response data. It also fails to bother sending another GET request to my api PDF creation url (/api/pdfsetlist) which would normally result in a PDF being sent back. I use  window.open("/api/pdfsetlist/" + currentSetlist.setlistID, "_blank") for this request so that the returning PDF is opened in another tab, or by another app if running from my phone. Instead, what I get in the resulting window is just a blank page as my App.js has no route for this url.

My API routes are served from the same domain as the app using a Node Express setup with defined routes for api addresses and a catch-all route at the end for serving the React App.
[Image showing nodejs express snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x95FS.jpg)

Any help with configuring service worker exceptions from (I think that's what I want to do) gratefully accepted.